# Finding x, y coordinates of color within image. Node JS

Tags: node.js, image, opencv

I would like to capture whole screen and then get the coordinates(x, y) of color which i provide. So i can click that coordinate with RobotJS.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more detail about your setup would be necessary. Since you tagged it, I guess you have access to OpenCV in your project? With OpenCV you can use 'inrange' to filter the channels of your image based on the color, which will give you a binary mask. You can use the mask to find blobs and their central points in your image, where the color predominates with connectedComponents or findContours.